# Run PHP scripts at different intervals using only one cron job

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a few PHP scripts that should run at different intervals like every minute, every hour, every day and so on, nothing too specific.

I want to creat a light-weight scheduler PHP class that works like the following:

all php scripts that need to be executed are in a folder called `jobs` and the scheduler file should be in the parent directory.

Each file in the `jobs` folder should contain information about how often it should run.
The scheduler file should be set via a cron job to run every minute so it can cover all those intervals. Furthermore I imagine it to include all files of the `jobs` folder and a task should run if the running criteria is met.

Ideally this should not use a database or some file storage.

I imagine the code to be like this:

scheduler.php

```
$base = dirname(__FILE__);
if ($handle = opendir($base.'/jobs')) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strpos($file,'.php') !== false) {
            include($base.'/jobs/'.$file);
        }
    }
  }
```

sample of a job.php

```
if(run_every_hour()) {
  Code...
}
```

My problem is to get a `run_every_hour()` or `run_every_minute()` function, how can I determine if a script should run without using some sort of database?

It could be possible to check the current time but that would be inaccurate and unreliable.

Any Suggestions on this?

I've looked for some scheduling scripts but they are all too complex and complicated. All I want is to adapt my if function condition to my job.php files and drop them into the jobs folder and they should run with no manual editing or something similar needed.

Comment: You need some sort of memory to track the state of jobs. Otherwise you risk strange effects when jobs take too long or the system gets stuffed with load. Whether you use a database or files for storage does not make a real difference. The easiest is to use mysql or sqlite for such tasks. Everything else adds costs.

Comment: What do you mean with current time being inaccurate and unreliable? That is pretty much the only way you can construct run_every_whatever() functions.